# Getting error after pod update to FBSDK 5.0.0 in x code 10.1

Tags: ios, xcode, fbsdkloginkit

I am trying to update my facebook SDK to 5.0.0 but after installing pod update, I keep getting this error in FBSDK Login Kit.

[image: error in FBSDK Login Kit]

[image: error in FBSDK Login Kit]

[image: error in FBSDK Login Kit]

This is my pod file.

```
pod 'FacebookSDK', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'FacebookSDK/LoginKit', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'FacebookSDK/ShareKit', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'FacebookSDK/PlacesKit', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.0.0'
```

Anyone please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I got solution. 
First I install FBSDK kits for version 5.0.2 like

```
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.0.2'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 5.0.2'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 5.0.2'
```

After you would see

```
Bolt.h file not found
```

Remove that `import bolt.h` line, and replace

```
[FBSDKBasicUtility objectForJSONString ...]
```

with

```
[FBSDKInternalUtility objectForJSONString ...].
```

When you are done change some codes that they suggest to current FBSDK version acceptable codes and it solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have getting wrong way. Sometimes pod is updated but some files may not get updated. So, you need to first uninstall FBSDK pod by removing

```
pod 'FacebookSDK', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'FacebookSDK/LoginKit', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'FacebookSDK/ShareKit', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'FacebookSDK/PlacesKit', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.0.0'
```

from pod file, and then run following command. You can also comment above pod and run command.

```
pod install
```

This will clear your old pod files.

Again, add above pods in pod file and run same command

```
pod install
```

will fix your issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But nothing changed after doing that. I also clean my project. But error haven't solved yet.

Comment: Actually same error I had faced, I have first completely removed `FBSDK` pod and then install again had fixed my issues.

Comment: Try again same without version.

Comment: Still not solving my issue.

Comment: By the way, what is your swift version?